# How and when to strip the url to serve a static site?

Tags: http, go, go-chi

I have the following directory structure for my static web site:

```
│   infinote.exe
└───spa
    │   favicon.ico
    │   index.html
    │
    ├───css
    │       app.f99f51d4.css
    │       vendor.d9e2261d.css
    │
    ├───fonts
    │       flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNa.40fa1be9.woff
    │       flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.cf9862e8.woff2
    │       KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxIIzQ.9391e6e2.woff
    │       KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc-.ddd11dab.woff
    │       KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc-.877b9231.woff
    │       KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc-.0344cc3c.woff
    │       KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc-.b555d228.woff
    │       KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.9b78ea3b.woff
    │       PatuaOne-Regular.ttf
    │       Poppins-Regular.ttf
    │
    ├───icons
    │       apple-icon-120x120.png
    │       apple-launch-828x1792.png
    │       favicon-128x128.png
    │       favicon-16x16.png
    │       favicon-32x32.png
    │       favicon-96x96.png
    │       icon-128x128.png
    │       safari-pinned-tab.svg
    │
    └───js
            app.3a5b0240.js
            vendor.a9a3886c.js
```

`infinote.exe` is a binary compiled from Go and the line where I define how to serve the web site is

```
r.Handle("/spa/", http.StripPrefix("/spa/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./spa"))))
```

I use [`chi`](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) as the router, and `r := chi.NewRouter()`.

I expect `http://example.com/spa/` to:

- first request `http://example.com/spa/` → this is `./spa/index.html`
- and then after parsing `index.html`, to request other files in `./spa`

  - An example would be `http://example.com/spa/js/vendor.a9a3886c.js` → `./spa/js/vendor.a9a3886c.js`

What happens is that `index.html` is retrieved correctly, and then all the referenced files return a `404 Not Found`.

To be frank I do not exactly understand the mechanics (and need) of `http.StripPrefix`. Is this because the files in `spa` are relative to the full URL, in other words to `./spa/spa/...`- which is not correct (and thus the need to strip `app` first)?

If so, why is only `index.html` retrieved correctly? Even `favicon.ico` is a 404 despite being in the same directory as `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

*All credit goes to [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) and [@Zombo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12258482/zombo) whose comments were, for some reason, deleted*

After several iterations and tests, I managed to find a working version:

```
r.Handle("/spa/*",http.StripPrefix("/spa/", ttp.FileServer(http.Dir("spa"))))
```

The key part was the `*` in the first "pattern". I did not find anything about wildcards in the documentation but with a `*` it works - and without it does not (I get the 404`).

I would be delighted to have an answer that is better than that

Comment: `*` is not a wildcard in the standard library's [`net/http.ServeMux`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.18.1#ServeMux). It has no special meaning. So if you say it works with `*` but not without, then that means you're not using the `net/http` package for *routing*. You're using something else. What is `r`?

Comment: When you use `net/http.ServeMux` then using `"/spa/"` will match requests to `/spa/` but also any requests that begin with `/spa/`, e.g. `/spa/js/vendor.a9a3886c.js`. And when you use `/spa` then only requests to `/spa` will be matched (and `/spa/` will automatically be redirected to `/spa` I believe), requests to other paths will not be handled.

Comment: Thi sis a good point, I completely forgot to mention it. I use [`chi`](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) and `r := chi.NewRouter()`. I do not see anything special about patterns in the docs, though. I updated the question as well

Comment: Right there in the package's [overview](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi@v1.5.4#pkg-overview) it mentions patterns, named placeholders, placeholders with regexp, and placeholders with asterisks. Examples are also included. Also at the bottom of the "Router Interface" section of the README, just above the ["Middleware handlers"](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi@v1.5.4#readme-middleware-handlers) section, you can see patterns and wildcards mentioned.

Comment: @mkopriva: thank you very much. I am new to Go and I realize now that the way the language and libraries are documented is different from what I know (as an amateur developer). The documentation in pkg.go.dev is really the reference, including discussions on usage, examples etc - I was rather relying on it as a kind of "API reference" with limited information outside of the technical usage. Thanks for pointing out the references as you did - I will from now on navigate all the docs for such libraries as what I am looking for is there, and not in the github repository . That was really useful.